# 3D representation of Google Maps/Routes?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, 3d

I need to build a `3d` live map of current airplane flights. It needs to be able to run on a browser without downloading any plugin (*cough* Google Earth *cough*).

I [*already managed doing*](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/20/) something similar with google map  :

[image]

But I need to be able to show it in a `3d - globe POV` :

something like : 
[image]

Is there anything I can do in google maps to make them globe-3d or is there something else (API) which I can use ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A good starting point may be [webgl-globe](http://code.google.com/p/webgl-globe/) from the Google Data Arts team.  It's built on [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) and webgl:

[image]

You'd have to change the bars to arcs, but it's a start :)

A caveat: webgl is the best way to get interactive 3d in the browser without other dependencies, but it isn't supported by safari or IE yet, or if the user is missing graphics drivers.

Comment: it's really a problem for me that it is not supported in IE...( and i tested it with ie10...)

Comment: There is a WebGL plugin for Internet Explorer: http://iewebgl.com . If that doesn't meet your needs, Microsoft have confirmed that WebGL support will be included in IE11: http://techcrunch.com/2013/06/26/microsoft-confirms-webgl-support-for-internet-explorer-11/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mercantor projection to map the sphere coordinate to the Google maps tiles, I. e.  pixelcoordinate. Then you can choose an open source library to draw to the canvas and then add some simple matrices transformation to rotate the globe. The tile mapping works with a quad key. It's describe here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

I remember seeing a tweet, I think by Paul Irish that allowed you to alter google maps using css to create a globe shape.

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/09/Interactive-Globe-with-CSS-shaders-Google-Maps

Don't know if it has been updated as it was the latest Chrome only but it may be worth taking a look.

Comment: Thanks but its only in canary with special settings (about:flags),--setting enable css shaders........... well I cant tell my clients to do that...:-)